How to change IntelliJ IDEA Gradle version
It keeps getting version 7.1 which is not supporting JMH, how can I tell it to use version 8.11? I don't have Gradle in path and also not found anything about 7.1 in any properties

Download Gradle https://gradle.org/install/ . Unzip it.
If you don't want latest version of Gradle, choose your preferred version at https://gradle.org/releases/ , you can download these versions.
With Windows Operating system: Set environment variable %GRADELE_HOME%
Set environment variable %PATH% add one entry
%GRADLE_HOME%\bin

macOS or Linux will be like this with a little different.
Go to menu File \ Settings


